# How to assign a static IP to linux host using Powershell DSC / Lability?

Tags: linux, powershell, hyper-v, dsc

**Setup**: I am using [Lability](https://github.com/VirtualEngine/Lability) to deploy a hacking lab consisting of 3 virtual machines. One of the machines is [Kali](https://www.kali.org/) Linux. How could I automatically set a static IP for the Kali when it is first deployed from the script?

**Problem**: Lability has very limited options to configure Linux hosts. No option to configure networking.

**Have tried:** 
[DSC for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/lnxgettingstarted) but not a solution because everything needs to installed from the Lability / DSC script. This is compulsory. DSC for Linux requires components installed on the Linux host, and these cannot be installed with Lability when deploying the virtual machines.

Can I bind the MAC address of the Kali network adapter somehow to a specific IP address? I can set up a DHCP server on one of the machines.

What other suggestions for solutions you see?

I am pretty invested in Lability / Desired State Configuration at this point and changing tools would likely be the prettiest solution but not viable considering time constraints.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can install Powershell Core for Linux.

[Installing Powershell Core on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6)

[Powershell in Linux](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/11/14/work-with-powershell-in-linux.aspx)

Normally in Windows we use Set-NetIPAddress to configure an IP Address. You can try and check if the command is available in Linux Powershell Core.

[About Set-NetIPAddress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netipaddress?view=win10-ps)